# using dropwdownlist to select option

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using a dropdwonlist in asp.net with c# i uploaded data dynamically from database in dropdownlist and keep the first text "select" on 0 index  when the form uploaded all the data showing but when when i select an option in dropdownlist it can not select only "select one" option selected and not mor  when i change the code which is below then give error 'ASP.product_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ddlcategory_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'ddlcategory_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.product_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) my code is below

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcategory" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcategory_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't make out anything from your question. What problem you are facing? Dropdown is not populated? Or you are not able to select value from it?

Comment: Can you please explain what is the exact issue you are facing? The question you mentioned doesn't make any sense. Otherwise please learn more about dropdown list on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcategory" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcategory_SelectedIndexChanged()" >
           
</asp:DropDownList>

Comment: the above is my code dropdownlist is pupolated but but can not change the index when i use the above index code it give error that indexmethod is unkown are you missing a directory this a hedic from 2 days please help me also applied on the below code but not worked

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcategory" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcategory_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

Comment: i am not able to select an option

Comment: Do you have method public method `ddlcategory_SelectedIndexChanged`  in the code behind of page?

Answer (score -1):

where you bind Dropdown ? check if you Populate Dropdown   in ( Not  Is Postpack) in page load

Comment: i bind dropdown from database dyanamicaly and after that add on 0 index by default "select" option keep the autopostback true in dropdownlist html code when i select other option then select it can't select and oly select option come in the tex of dropdownlist

Comment: i have solve the problem of selection on jus code <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                       AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
                    </asp:DropDownList> but now the problem is that each time when i select an option it generate the duplication of all values in dropdownlist how can avoid this

Comment: please any once can help me when i click an option in dropdownlist it generate the duplicate of all option in dropdownlist how to prevent it in c sharp and asp.net